# Export data from Access to Excel and batch every 1000 records in individual cells

Tags: ms-access, vba

A customer has asked to me export a recordset (which equates to one column) from access to excel – which I'm fine with using VBA.  However, they want the data batched, so every 1000 records will be placed in one cell and so on.  They have asked that the records are separated by a comma.  I suspect they are then feeding the records into another application (like Business Objects).

So for example:
cell A1 would look like:  1235,1234,2346,346 etc
cell B2 would look like: 7994,345,345

Can anyone offer any help on this as I'm stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a query to return one record every 1000 records and concatenate them into a single field and then export it to excel as you already have done.

Using [this](http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html) function in your query you can concatenate grouped records into a single field. You can group them every 1000 using a row counter dividing for 1000 and taking the integer part.

Comment: this is great however, doesn't access limit field characters to 250, so 1000 wouldn't work?

Comment: You will probably need a memo or text type field, because your rows would be much more than 1000 characters

Comment: do you know how I would batch by 1000 rows as this is just doing it one by one

Comment: Before the query within the concatRelated function you need to create a query with the same value for first the 1000 records and another value for 1001 to 2000 and so on. After that you can use this field as the group related field.